# AWTSequenceEncoder does not exist in jcodec 2.5.0?

Tags: java, awt, video-encoding, video-recording, jcodec

I am trying to use JCodec to make a screen-recording software in Java.
I am having trouble finding where `AWTSequenceEncoder` is located, or if it even exists in JCodec still.
I am using JCodec 2.5.0 for javase. Java 8. Does anyone know if this class (`AWTSequenceEncoder`) still exists in the library or do i have to use a copy-pasted version of the file from JCodec's github?

thanks! gavin

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal rewrite of your question:

> *Is `AWTSequenceEncoder` still present in jcodec? If so, where can it be found?*

Yes, `AWTSequenceEncoder` is still present in "jcodec". It is part of the package `org.jcodec.javase.api.awt.AWTSequenceEncoder`, and can be found in the github repo here:

- https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/javase/src/main/java/org/jcodec/javase/api/awt/AWTSequenceEncoder.java

The [README](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/README.md) has various examples, including this (I copied only one line here):

```
AWTSequenceEncoder encoder = new AWTSequenceEncoder(out, Rational.R(25, 1));
```